# How do you coordinate redirects between a mobile and full website?

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a full website and recently added a mobile website. The first thing I did was to redirect calls to the full website from mobile devices to the mobile website. My web.config rules are as follows:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<clear />
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="ipad" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="mobi" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone|android|iphone" />
    </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.wkmclaughlin.mobi" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

RequestBlockingRule1 looks for a mobile device in the HTTP_USER_AGENT portion of the request and redirects the request to the mobile website if it finds one; RequestBlockingRule2 intercepts requests from iPad devices and requests with “mobi” in the QUERY_STRING to prevent the redirection from occurring.

The problem is that I need to make calls to the full website from the mobile website and cannot do it with these redirects in place.  I thought URL Rewrite was only for remote calls to the website, but it seems to process local requests as well.  First, it can’t find AC_RunActiveContent.js; when the screen finally forms, all the graphics are gone and the remaining hyperlinks don’t do anything.

But if I temporarily remove the two rules, the full website displays properly.  CAN you be routing mobile devices to your mobile website AND display your full website via your mobile site where people are using mobile devices?  If so, what changes are needed in the rewrite rules?
[image: with and without redirects]

Comment: I've noticed that eliminating RequestBlockingRule1 doesn't change anything -- the relative addressing on the website still doesn't work anymore.  But if I remove RequestBlockingRule2 as well, the site displays fine.  How can RequestBlockingRule2 be destroying the relative addressing?  It's supposed to do nothing.

Comment: Also: the iPad portion of the rule works perfectly … an iPad displays the site perfectly with no relative path issues.  But the query string flag does not result in a similar connection -- it connects to the page in a way where relative addressing doesn't work.